How to train a neural network
I recently came across this neural network and wanted to run it, but as it turned out, it can't solve the equation a+b*c/d correctly, apparently it needs to be trained somehow, but I don't quite understand how to do it. I have only recently started studying neural networks, I would appreciate it if you could help.
import numpy as np

# Define the neural network architecture
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weights = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])  # Weights for the input values

    def forward(self, inputs):
        return np.dot(inputs, self.weights)

# Define the equation to evaluate
equation = "2+3*10/9"

# Preprocess the equation
equation = equation.replace(" ", "")  # Remove any spaces

# Split the equation into operands and operators
operands = []
operators = []

current_operand = ""
for char in equation:
    if char.isdigit() or char == ".":
        current_operand += char
    else:
        operands.append(float(current_operand))
        current_operand = ""
        operators.append(char)

# Add the last operand
operands.append(float(current_operand))

# Create input array
inputs = np.array(operands[:-1])  # Exclude the last operand (result)

# Evaluate the equation using the neural network
neural_network = NeuralNetwork()
output = neural_network.forward(inputs)

# Apply the operators to the output sequentially
for operator, operand in zip(operators, operands[1:]):
    if operator == "+":
        output += operand
    elif operator == "-":
        output -= operand
    elif operator == "*":
        output *= operand
    elif operator == "/":
        output /= operand

# Print the result
print(f"Equation: {equation}")
print(f"Output: {output}")

I tried to look for solutions, but nothing came of it.

The code doesn't include any training process. Neural networks learn by adjusting their weights based on examples and a loss function, which is entirely missing here.

Is it possible to somehow change the code so that learning is possible?
